# What are the limitations on the "Dueling" fighting style for Fighters?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, shield, fighting-style

So I was looking over the wording for the fighting styles for Fighters, and I notices the wording for the *Dueling* Fighting Style **(p. 72 PHB)** seemed to allow for more options than you would automatically assume.

> **Dueling: When you are wielding a melee weapon in one hand and no other weapons, you gain a +2 bonus to damage rolls with that weapon.**

So if I am reading this correctly... and I'd like to think I am, I could take this as a fighting style, and still use a shield in my other hand, since, *as it was worded*, it's not a **weapon**.

Now of course this whether you could do this or not, at the end of the day is at your GM's discretion, but as far as the rules go as stated in **PHB** it is a viable course of action, yes?

Comment: Yes, you can use a sword and shield. Shields are not weapons.